# Changing the position of a defined string from the end to the front of the rest of the string

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

| Compartment |
| --- |
| #1 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #2 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| SINGLE POINT DAVIT HPU |
| CENTRAL HYDRAULIC SYSTEM |
| #1 MAIN DIESEL ENGINE |
| #2 MAIN DIESEL ENGINE |
| CPP #1 |
| CPP #2 |
| #3 SSDG |
| EDG |
| #1 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #2 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #2 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #1 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #1 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #2 Z-DRIVE HYDRAULIC |
| #1 SSDG |
| #2 SSDG |
| #3 SSDG |
| #1 MAIN DIESEL ENGINE |
| #2 MAIN DIESEL ENGINE |

If the #X is at the end of the string, I would like to move it to the front of the string, eg:

Before: CPP #1

After: #1 CPP

Comment: Please post your input as text and not picture

Comment: @Amira Just did. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try the solution I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the string into 2 parts: a part before the "#" and a part after the "#" and then concatenate the parts in reverse order, placing the part after the "#" first followed by the "#" and then the part before the "#".

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Compartment", each 
        let
            parts = Text.Split(_, " "),
            lastPart = List.Last(parts),
            isNumbered = Text.StartsWith(lastPart, "#")
        in
            if isNumbered then
                Text.Combine({lastPart} & List.RemoveLastN(parts, 1), " ")
            else
                _, type text})
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It returned the following error: Expression.Error: 3 arguments were passed to a function which expects 2.

Comment: I removed the argument 2 from Text.Split and it seemed to have done the trick. However, the strings that were initially correct are now looking like this: 2 #STEERING GEAR HPU.

Comment: /////////////Gracias!

Comment: De naadaaaa senor